# What does the small number on top of the square root symbol mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

I just came across this annotation in my school's maths compendium:

[image: Screenshot]

The compendium is very brief and doesn't explain what this means.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the inverse function of $a^n$. Hence $\sqrt[n]a$ means, you look for a number $b$, which when multiplied $n$ times with itself results in $a$.

For instance: We know that $2^3 = 8$, so $\sqrt[3]8 = 2$, $\sqrt[5]{-1}=-1$ because $(-1)^5 = -1$.
$\sqrt[4]3 \approx 1.31607$ because $1.31607^4 \approx 3$.

If there is no number at the top of the root symbol, it means $n=2$, so $\sqrt[2]a = \sqrt a$.

Comment: Very well explained, thank you

Comment: I would not recommend to use this notation with negative numbers as you did.

Comment: Could you explain why $(-1)^5=-1\sqrt[4]{3}$? I'm really confused on that.

Comment: @Travis It is not. These are two examples. The first example is: $(-1)^5 = -1$ and the second one is $\sqrt[4]3 \approx 1.31607$.

Comment: Oh, didn't see the comma. Thanks.

Comment: Bad to use negative numbers in there, as the poster of the question is not yet familiar with complex numbers.

Answer (score 12):

It means that instead of the "square root of a" you are now considering the "nth root of a".  This is the same as writing $a^{1 \over n}$.  And just like the square root is "undone" by applying a squared term, i.e., $(\sqrt a)^2 = a$, so the nth root is "undone" by applying the nth power, i.e., $(\sqrt[n] a)^n = a$.

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt[n] a$=$a^ \frac 1 n$

Also,if $\sqrt[n] a$=$x$ then $x^n=a$

Comment: @Olorun-Didn't notice that it was 2 year old...may be it was recently modified....saw it in the newest questions tab...

Comment: Different answers teach different and sometimes new things, and I see no problem with new answers, given to old posts.

Comment: Minor point: I notice quite a few elementary algebra books as well as some writers here taking the view that the n-th root of x is defined as x to the power 1/n. I disagree strongly. For an elementary student, the idea of saying "what raised to the n-th power gives x?" is more straightforward than saying "just raise x to the power 1/n" particularly since the way one does this without a calculator is the former, not the latter. That is, x to the power 1/n should be the entity being defined, with it defined as I've described - and not the reverse.